# Which one is faster to access Qualifiers opencl?

Tags: opencl

I was wondering from technical point of view which one of the following in opencl in faster to access ??

```
__global
__local
__constant
__private
```

Answer (score 2):

`private` memory space is fastest (0 clock cycle access latency). `private` variables are stored in on-chip registers of the GPU. You use this for any temporary variables.

`local` memory space is still fast, but slower than `private`. `local` variables are still stored on-chip, but as part of the L1 cache. Access latency is 4-8 clock cycles. You use this for inter-thread-communication within thread blocks, for example during matrix multiplication (cache tiling).

`constant` memory space is part of the video memory (slow access, high latency). But it is read-only and is automatically cached on-chip if used repeatedly. You use `constant` for large lookup tables for example.

`global` memory space is GPU video memory (or system memory if you run OpenCL on the CPU). Access latency is very high at 400-800 clock cycles. You use `global` for any large data fiels that you do processing on.

There is also the `host` memory space. This is CPU main memory and access is only possible via PCIe copy into video memory first. This is very slow compared to the other memory spaces.

For further information, see

- [OpenCL Best Practices Guide](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15668-s11/www/cuda-doc/OpenCL_Best_Practices_Guide.pdf)
- [OpenCL Optimization](https://www.nvidia.com/content/GTC/documents/1068_GTC09.pdf)
- [OpenCL Programming Guide for the CUDA Architecture](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/OpenCL/doc/OpenCL_Programming_Guide.pdf)

Comment: You should probably add a disclaimer that this *mostly* reflects the de-facto situation, although is not guaranteed by the standard. Also, I believe for AMD GPUs, `constant` tends to be very fast (not caching as such, but there is small, dedicated on-chip memory for it) as long as it doesn't "spill" into global memory by trying to use too much of it.